# Browser Window width smaller than expected when querying with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compute the header's width and height in a dynamic manner using the window's height and width.

The problem is they get smaller with 16 pixels and I don't know why.

This is what I expect to get:

1. w_height: 929, w_width: 1280
2. body_height: 929 - top - bottom - border(1px top, 1px bottom) = 727
3. body_width: 1280 - left - right - border(1px left, 1px right) = 878

This is what I get:

1. body_height: 711
2. body_width: 867

Can you tell me how can I fix this and why does this thing occur?
Thank you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dancing Web</title>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        body{
            position:absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 200px;
            right: 200px;
            bottom: 100px;  
        }
        figure{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        .solid_border{
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="solid_border">
        <header>

            <figure >

            </figure>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){          
                alert($(window).height() +', '+$(window).width());
                alert($('body').css('height') +', '+$('body').css('width'));        
            });
        </script>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
alert($(window).outerHeight() +', '+$(window).outerWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you should get the outer width and height.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/
- http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

because of padding, border, eventually margins.